# Why I don't see the ICEfaces ace:sliderEntry?

Tags: jsf, slider, icefaces

I have a problem that I can't fix for a very long time. I can't use icefaces sliderEntry in my project, I do this:

**pom:**

```
<repository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <url>http://anonsvn.icefaces.org/repo/maven2/releases/</url>
        </repository>
```

and more:

```
 <dependency>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>icefaces-ace</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

**in my xhtml:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
      lang="en"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
      xmlns:ace="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components"
>
```

**so I call the slider:**

```
<h:form>
      <ace:sliderEntry />
</h:form>
```

But I don't see it on my page, the debugging tools also don't say anything useful. Maybe I ported something wrong?

**UPD**
I noticed that this element in the browser has the hidden type, why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>icefaces-ace</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

and be sure that all the icefaces libraries have a "compile" scope

You need also use `<h:body>` instead of default `<body>` tags